# Accessing jQuery ui object from Accordion change function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

This should be really simple, but I can't seem to figure out what to do. I'm trying to figure out if a clicked on section in a jQuery accordion has a class. If it does, we need to execute a function. So far, I've found that I can examine the content section being acted on using the following in the change function:

```
console.log(ui.newContent);
```

Looking at the object in Firebug, I can see there's a 0 index. Clicking on the 0 to expand it in Firebug reveals it has something listed as "get classList" as one of the object properties. However, neither of the following work to access this:

```
console.log(ui.newContent[0].classList);
console.log(ui.newContent[0].classList());
```

However, I was able to get the object's id via this:

```
console.log(ui.newContent[0].id);
```

So, out of curiosity, anyone know how to access the classList, or am I just going to have to use the id as a selector and get the object again so I can use .hasClass on it? Seems like a waste but its a possible workaround. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update: I've found I could also search the className string for the same effect. Is this best practice? Might be more efficient than looping through the array of classes if I could even access them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.hasClass() should work for you. In your handler:

```
if(ui.newContent.hasClass('foo')) {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: You're completely right. Apparently I only tried using .hasClass on ui.newContent[0]. Doh!

Comment: Easy mistake to make. ui.newContent is a jQuery object containing the just-selected content in the accordion. When you index into a jQuery object via ui.newContent[0], jQuery returns a DOM object, which is why hasClass and other jQuery methods are no longer present.